# HQL query where exists or between list elements

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a Tag class like this:

```
public class Tag {

    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private Set<Document> documents = new HashSet<Document>();

    public Tag(){}

//getter and setter...

}
```

And a class Document clasified by some tags object

```
public class Document {

    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private Int numberPages;
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();

    public Document(){}

//getter and setter...

}
```

And now I would like get documents with a 10 pages maximun and they have tags "short" OR "essay"

I guess something like:

```
int nPages = 10;
Query query = session.createQuery("from Document where nPages <= :numberPages and (<<short>> OR <<essay>>);  
query.setInteger("numberPages", nPages);
```

The list of tags could be variable. And I would like differentiate when have to be all tags ("AND" between tags) or with any tag is enough ("OR" between tags)

How can I build the sql statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `HQL` should look like below:

```
  Query query = session.createQuery(
           "from Document d join d.tags t "+
           " where d.nPages <= :numberPages and "+
              " t.title in (:titles) "; 
  List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
  titles.add("short");
  titles.add("essay");
  query.setParameter("numberPages", nPages);  
  query.setParameterList("titles", titles);
```

Comment: This returns objects which have only tags "short" AND "essay" or any object that has "short" OR "essay"?

Comment: @Franb Any object which is short "OR" essay OR both. Do you need "AND" ONLY?

Comment: Really not, "AND" ONLY, was for curiosity only. I think with OR is enough, although I guess I will order result by occurrence. For example an object with these two tags is "more important" than other object with only one them. I guess Hibernate can't return an ordered list.

Comment: @Franb You may want to use the `Order By` clause as well.